# Opal loads in Chrome but not in Node (ReferenceError: Opal is not defined)

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, google-chrome, opalrb

For example, if I just run the following:

`node opal.min.js`

The result is:

`/home/benjamin/workspace/1/opal.min.js:1
klass){return obj.toString()}else{return obj.$inspect()}})}(self)})(Opal);(fun
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: Opal is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/benjamin/workspace/1/opal.min.js:1:15264)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3`

However, if I load opal in a page in Chrome and compile a "hello world" script, it runs just fine with no complaint.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  I'd really like to be able to run these scripts using Node.

Comment: Which version are you using? v0.7 (beta) should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Opal v0.7 has been released with [explicit Node.js support](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/runtime.js#L1430-L1439).

In fact Node.js is the default runner for the CLI and there's a `nodejs` file in stdlib that will add a (basic) platform specific implementation of File, Dir, IO, etc. E.g.:

```
$ opal -rnodejs -e 'exit 127'
$ echo $?
127
```

Comment: Your example does not work.
```$ opal -rnodejs -e 'exit 127'

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at Function.require [as node_require] (module.js:380:17)
    at OpalClass.$node_require (/tmp/opal-nodejs-runner-20150209-17507-pm733y:12901:23)
    at /tmp/opal-nodejs-runner-20150209-17507-pm733y:13078:26
    at Opal.modules.nodejs/dir (/tmp/opal-nodejs-runner-20150209-17507-...
```

Comment: This is using the latest version of opal. (Opal v0.7.0)

Comment: yeah sorry you need to install `npm install -g glob`

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but it didn't.  I'm still getting the same error.  ```opal -v``` ```Opal v0.7.0```

Comment: Core team bias, was working on my machine because I ran it from the opal project dir which happens to contain a `node_modules` dir with `glob` installed. Need to dig deeper.

Comment: Ok, in next release the node_modules dir will be shipped in the gem and I'll try to respect local and global node_modules dirs as well (that depends on how that works on node).

Comment: In the meanwhile this works (after installing `glob`): `opal -rnodejs -ce 'exit 127' | node; echo $?`

Comment: I've installed glob.  The same problem continues to occur.  I have even tried this on separate computers.

Comment: Forward some months, now 0.8.1 is out and works properly (just tested in a clean docker container: https://gist.github.com/elia/868754d0e4891005d5ef) no need to install `glob` anymore.